# How to set HTML attribute in conditional rule with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm still confused about how to set other class attribute in an element according to other element attribute in dynamic number.

Here are my HTML & PHP:

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++){ ?>
<a href="#no<?php echo $i;?>" id="shorcut<?php echo $i;?>" class"not-yet"><?php echo $i;?></a>
<?php } ?>

<div id="no<?php echo $no?>" class="<?php if(!empty($h->answer)){ echo 'answered';} else{ echo 'not-yet';} ?>">
```

And here are my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var i;
 var tot = <?php echo $jumlah;?>
 for (i=1; i< tot; i++){
    if($('#no'+i).hasClass('answered'){
       $('#shortcut'+i).attr('class', 'answered');
    }
 }
});
```

For example when `<div id="1">` has a class attribute `"answered"` then set `<a href="no1" id="shortcut1" class="answered">` (change class from `"not-yet"` to `"answered"`)

Help me and thanks for your attention

Comment: #SOLVED

I've recheck my script and it has syntax error in var tot = <?php echo $jumlah;?> with no ending ";" and if($('#no'+i).hasClass('answered'){ with no ")"

Comment: You should upvote answers that you feel are helpful or valuable (or answers the question you asked). I would suggest at _least_ doing this for the answer you've accepted. This will help people who see your question in the future, and it will make the people who answer your questions happy. If you find the answer yourself, you can also enter an answer to your own question (or edit your question, but please don't edit it so the answers you've gotten don't make sense anymore). ps: the missing semicolon isn't a syntax error. pps: I fixed both your syntax issues in my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution to your javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/w9uvR/

Basically you just want to do this for each div:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("[id^='no']").each(function() {
            if(this.className == "answered") {
               var myId = this.id.replace("no","");
                $("#shortcut" + myId).attr("class", "answered");
             }
        })
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but I have changed my own code :

I've recheck my script and it has syntax error in var tot = <?php echo $jumlah;?> with no ending ";" and if($('#no'+i).hasClass('answered'){ with no ")"

But your tutorial is nice too :D Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(..).addClass('classname')` and `$(..).removeClass('classname')` to change class attributes.

```
$(function(){
    var tot = <?php echo $jumlah;?>;
    var i;
    for (i=1; i<tot; i++) {
       if ($('#no'+i).hasClass('answered')) {
           $('#shortcut'+i).addClass('answered');
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm still confused in conditional javascript when page onload.

Comment: is addClass function is permanently? my problem is when page reload it will back to default class

Comment: All jQuery functions act on the DOM in the browser and not on the html you're serving..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. But I've recheck my script and it has syntax error in var tot = <?php echo $jumlah;?> with no ending ";" and if($('#no'+i).hasClass('answered'){ with no ")"

Comment: and I still use this $('#shortcut'+i).attr('class', 'answered'); to change class attribute.